# Calculate the number of matches that satisfy the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with ID's and values.

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 10 |

I need to calculate number of rows which fit some conditions. For example if value<4 then count of matches, if value >=4 and value<=8 then count of rows, if value>8 then count of rows.

In the result I need to get following

| class | matches |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Don't understand how to make it in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `Case When...` and `Group By` you can handle it, like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Value <4 THEN '1'
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN Value >= 4
                         AND Value<8 THEN '2'
                    ELSE '3'
                END
       END AS CLASS,
       Count(*) matches
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN Value <4 THEN '1'
             ELSE CASE
                      WHEN Value >= 4
                           AND Value<8 THEN '2'
                      ELSE '3'
                  END
         END
```